# Keras: Get True labels (y_test) from ImageDataGenerator or predict_generator

Tags: keras

I am using `ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(...)` to generate batches of data from directories.

After the model builds successfully I'd like to get a two column array of True and Predicted class labels. With `model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=NUM_STEPS)` I can get a numpy array of predicted classes. Is it possible to have the `predict_generator` output the corresponding True class labels?

To add: validation_generator.classes does print the True labels but in the order that they are retrieved from the directory, it doesn't take into account the batching or sample expansion by augmentation.

Comment: Note that we shouldn't add data augmentation on the validation and test sets/generators.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the prediction labels by:

```
 y_pred = numpy.rint(predictions)
```

and you can get the true labels by:

```
y_true = validation_generator.classes
```

You should set `shuffle=False` in the validation generator before this.

Finally, you can print confusion matrix by

`print confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)`

Comment: @Kasra, can you give details about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's another, slightly "hackier" way, of retrieving the true labels as well. **Note that this approach can handle when setting `shuffle=True` in your generator** (it's generally speaking a good idea to shuffle your data - either if you do this manually where you've stored the data, or through the generator, which is probably easier). You will need your model for this approach though.

```
# Create lists for storing the predictions and labels
predictions = []
labels = []

# Get the total number of labels in generator 
# (i.e. the length of the dataset where the generator generates batches from)
n = len(generator.labels)

# Loop over the generator
for data, label in generator:
    # Make predictions on data using the model. Store the results.
    predictions.extend(model.predict(data).flatten())

    # Store corresponding labels
    labels.extend(label)

    # We have to break out from the generator when we've processed 
    # the entire once (otherwise we would end up with duplicates). 
    if (len(label) < generator.batch_size) and (len(predictions) == n):
        break
```

Your predictions and corresponding labels should now be stored in `predictions` and `labels`, respectively.

Lastly, remember that we should NOT add data augmentation on the validation and test sets/generators.

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.rint()` method will get one hot coding result like [1., 0., 0.] which once I've tried creating a confusion matrix with `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)` it caused error. Because `validation_generator.classes` returns class labels as a single number.

In order to get a class number for example 0, 1, 2 as class label specified, I have found the selected answer in this topic useful. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909971/15510504)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to resolve the class probabilities and convert it to a single class based on the score.

```
if Y_preds.ndim !=1:
    Y_preds = np.argmax(Y_preds, axis=1)
```